# Why is Flutter AdMob Ad Not Appearing?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-mobile-ads

Test Ad is Working Without Problem in Flutter App. However, when I enter my own Advertising ID, my banner ad does not appear in my application, what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

If it's your first time with Admob, and it worked on the test but it's not showing when you use your banner ads, you just need to wait.
It takes some time because Admob needs to verify your app and your contents, then it will show normally.

Comment: How long does it take for our ad to be approved?